# fullPage.js dynamical slides with ACF last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js

I am creating a dynamic full page slider with fullPage.js and Advanced Custom fields plugin for Wordpress.

```
 <div id="fullpage">
    <?php if(get_field('slide')): ?>
            <?php while(has_sub_field('slide')): ?>
        <div class="section" id="home">
                    <?php the_sub_field('slide_text'); ?>
        </div>
            <?php  endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The slider also has a down-arrow to show down movement and I would like for it to change to up-arrow icon when I reach the last slide, something like this:

```
   if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $('.ion-chevron-up').addClass('ion-chevron-down').removeClass('ion-chevron-up');
   } else if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 15) {
        $('.ion-chevron-down').addClass('ion-chevron-up').removeClass('ion-chevron-down');  
    } else { 
    // nothing
    }
```

How can I determine the last slide of fullPage.js dynamically and achieve this?

**EDIT**

I ended up using

```
.fp-viewing-1 .ion-chevron-down {
  display: none;
}
.fp-viewing-0 .ion-chevron-up {
  display: none;
}
```

Although this is not dynamic since on the client side there can be slides added so this is not really the solution. I'd really need a class fp-viewing-x which would be for the last slide, whatever the number would be.

Comment: Just a note...with that loop, you're ending up with divs that have the same `id`...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Honest mistake

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `scrollTop` unless you use `scrollBar:true` .(Read the [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions) for more info).

Use instead the callbacks provided by the plugin such as `afterLoad`.

Then check that the section with the `active` class is the last one with something like:

```
if ( $('.section.active').is(':last-child'))
```

Or you can even use the class `fp-viewing-xxx` added to the `body` element to your site and just deal with CSS. (which would be my option)

Comment: I added scrollBar true, thanks. I've tried implementing this with jquery: 

 `$(document).ready(function() {
if ( $('.section.active').is(':last-child')) {
    $('span.ion-chevron-down').addClass('ion-chevron-up').removeClass('ion-chevron-down');
} else {
 $('span.ion-chevron-up').addClass('ion-chevron-down').removeClass('ion-chevron-up');
}
});`

But somehow this doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: Reproduce the issue in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/418/) for a further examination. Without a reproduction of it I can not help you more.